# How to use Custom Date /time picker as a function

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I've created a **custom date&time** picker and i'm using the same picker at four places in my app. but with different button names. the code is quite large so I thought of creating a seperate class and put the picker in that class inside a function. But after doing so i'm not able to return the current date, as soon as I call the function from the another class it immediately return null even before selecting the date and time . 
Here is the custom DateTime Picker Class:

```
public class DateTimePicker {

String str,samay;
public String returnDate(final Context ctx)

{


    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    final DatePicker picker1 = new DatePicker(ctx);

    try {
        Field f[] = picker1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f) {
            if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker")|| field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner") ) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object yearPicker = new Object();
                yearPicker = field.get(picker1);
                ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    picker1.setCalendarViewShown(false);

    builder1.setTitle("Please select date on which you would be leaving :")
            .setView(picker1)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
                            Date date1=new Date();
                            date1.setDate(picker1.getDayOfMonth());
                            date1.setMonth(picker1.getMonth());
                            final String s =parseFormat.format(date1);
                            Log.e("DATE",s);



                            //Time picker
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                            final TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(ctx);
                            picker.setIs24HourView(true);
                            builder.setTitle("Please select time at which you would be leaving :")
                                    .setView(picker)
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                    int hour=picker.getCurrentHour();
                                                    int minute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

                                                    str=s +" "+hour+":"+minute;

                                                }
                                            })
                                    .setNegativeButton("One way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }).create().show();
                            //Time picker


                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("One way",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .create().show();

    return "TIME "+str ;
}
```

}

In this way it return Time Null. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you get null because dateTimePicker dialog will need user interaction before providing a valid date time, whereas your function will return immediately after showing the picker dialog.

You can implement something like this:

```
/**
 * Method Sets the date using Default Date Picker and fills it in EditText
 * 
 * @param edittext
 * @param context
 * @param sharedprefs
 */
public void setDate(final EditText edittext) {

    String date = edittext.getTag(R.id.tag_date_time).toString();
    String[] splittedDate = date.split("-");
    int year = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[YEAR]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[MONTH]);
    int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[DATE]);
    DatePickerDialog datedialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    edittext.setText(year + "-"
                            + String.format("%02d", (monthOfYear + 1))
                            + "-" + String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth));
                    edittext.setTag(R.id.tag_date_time, (year + "-"
                            + String.format("%02d", (monthOfYear + 1))
                            + "-" + String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth)));
                }
            }, year, (month - 1), dayOfMonth);
    datedialog.show();

}
```

Here we are passing the target `editText` in which date need to be set. Function takes care of setting the date in `edittext` after user selects a date. Similar approach can be used with other pickers (`timePicker` , `dateTimePicker`) and view types(`textView`) as well.

Comment: but how can i setText from a function

Comment: if you observe carefully, we are passing reference to the `editText` which need to be updated in this function. now function is having instance of `editText` and can easily call `setText` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing the stuffs wrong way.

1. Create separate class `CustomDateTimePicker`
2. Create one method names showDateTimePicker() in which you will do the dialog stuff and will eventually show the dialog as well.
3. create Interface which will help you to get callbacks based on dialog press events.
4. implement the interface in parent activity.
5. Now before showing the dialog set Listener that will link with your activity.
6. Upon getting events from dialog call relevant method of your interface.

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this way